# Azure SQL Database trigger is not running and I cannot seem to figure out why

Tags: sql, azure, triggers, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to update the status column of a table when the table has been edited. I use a similar trigger on another table to update this status but when I try to put the trigger on the table itself it will not run.

```
ALTER TRIGGER dbo.tr_Invoice_SetInvoiceStatus_Update 
ON dbo.Invoice 
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @InvoiceID int
DECLARE @TotalInvoice DECIMAL(18,2)
DECLARE @TotalPayments DECIMAL(18,2)
DECLARE @InvoiceStatus NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @InvoiceStatusID INT


SELECT @InvoiceID = ID
FROM Inserted i


SELECT @TotalPayments = IsNull(Sum(ph.Amount), 0)
FROM PaymentHistory ph
WHERE InvoiceID = @InvoiceID

SELECT @TotalInvoice = ISNULL(Total, 0)
FROM Invoice
WHERE ID = @InvoiceID

IF (@TotalPayments > 0)
BEGIN       
    IF (@TotalPayments >= @TotalInvoice)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @InvoiceStatus = 'Paid'
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT @InvoiceStatus = 'Partially Paid'
    END     
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT @InvoiceStatus = 'Open'
END

SELECT @InvoiceStatusID = ID
FROM dbo.InvoiceStatus
WHERE [Name] = @InvoiceStatus

UPDATE dbo.Invoice
SET InvoiceStatusID = @InvoiceStatusID
WHERE ID = @InvoiceID

END
GO
```

Any help would be great?

Comment: not running? or just not doing anything.

Comment: Its executing the trigger at all.

Comment: Show the statement you are running on the base table - the UPDATE or INSERT against Invoice that would cause it to fire the trigger. Nested triggers aren't supported in Azure SQL so if you are expecting to recurse then it won't.